# Mongodb Assertion failure a <= 512*1024*1024

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb just crashed, can anyone tell me what happened?

the log can be found here, it was too big for stckoverflow

http://pastebin.com/HyXSti1Q

Comment: I have searched around a bit and found a trail, i.e.: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6806 it seems every single one results in some kind of bug report, you may wish to open a ticket at jira.mongodb.com

Comment: i created an issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14751

Comment: what is the mongodb version you are using?

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, were you creating a spatial index?

Comment: no you can see the index in the first line of the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the index can't be created if theres already too much data, when i first create the index and then insert data it works